# this code is for android app that plays the ringtone as per battery % i want it to run in backgroud,

Tags: android

Actually this works only if the app is open , i want it to run in background so that when battery level comes to a certain level it will play the sound?like suppose i want to play the tone as soon as battery becomes 50% without opening the app,app should run in background and as battery % becomes 50 it automatically starts playing the sound

java:

```
package com.example.abhi.fullbattery;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
 Button Btnstart,Btnstop;
    MediaPlayer mpAudio;
    //TextView txtView;
   // String hello;
    Intent batteryStatus;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Btnstart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Btnstart);
        Btnstop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Btnstop);
        mpAudio=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.police);
        Btnstart.setOnClickListener(this);
        Btnstop.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v==Btnstart)
        {
            batteryStatus = registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
            int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
            if (level==60)
            {
                mpAudio.start();
            }

        }
        else if(v==Btnstop)
        {
            mpAudio.pause();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use broadcastlistener to run in background and report when the battery level is changed, in the onReceive method of broadcast check if the level<50 then play the alert sound

```
public void onCreate()
{

this.registerReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver, 
        new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
}

private BroadcastReceiver mBatInfoReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent) {

    int level = intent.getIntExtra("level", 0);
    Log.e("test", String.valueOf(level) + "%");
    if(level<=50){
     //play alert sound    
     }
};


public void onDestroy(){
// unregister receiver
this.unregisterReceiver(this.mBatInfoReceiver);
}
```

Tutorial on how to use BroadcastReceiver and what all needs to be done for implementing BroadCastListener can be found in this link: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm